# AH02429: Response header name 'record Created - ' contains invalid characters, aborting request

Tags: linux, spring, apache, api, http-headers

I have created a restful api with basic authentication and works well with mi IDE and Tomcat, and I have tested with Postman. However when I deploy it into a linux server and I have got the following error in the error.log:

```
- AH02429: Response header name 'record Created  - ' contains invalid characters,   aborting request
```

I don't understand why I have this error as this works well before deployment.
Do I need to configured the server?
Please Help.

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/record/add/"}, method={org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST}, produces={"application/json"})
public ResponseEntity<Employee> createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    if (employee == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    employeeService.createEmployee(employee);
    headers.add("record Created  - ", String.valueOf(employee.getId()));
    return new ResponseEntity(employee, headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

When I try to insert/create a record using postman:

`{
    "id": 1,
    "surname": "Flores",
    "address1": "igle",
    "town": "campo",
    "postcode": "g",
    "c_b_name": "Charles",
    "b_event": "Chavan"
}`

I have the following error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
    <p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
    <p>Please contact the server administrator at 
webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred,
and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
    <p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
    <p>Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
    <hr>
    <address>Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at xxxxxxxx.com Port 80</address>
</body>
</html>
```

In the server error.log I have the following error:

```
Response header name 'record Created  - ' contains invalid characters, aborting request
```

Comment: where do you create the header with name `record Created  - `? In your code I don't see it

Comment: I have created a record in Postman, The record created have been added to database but gives the  - AH02429: Response header name 'record Created  - ' contains invalid characters,   aborting request in the log.error

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by removing the httpHeaders from the controller.